# Add RadioGroup to AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, radio-group

I need to add a radiogroup to an AlertDialog, so i write the follow code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder screenDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
screenDialog.setTitle("Captured Screen");

RadioGroup azione = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.azione_stop);

LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
dialogLayout.addView(azione);
screenDialog.setView(dialogLayout);
screenDialog.show();
```

And this is the xml containing the RadioGroup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/azione_stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ritornare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Ritornare" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/chiudi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#
        android:text="Chiudi chiamata" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/offerta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Segna offerta" />
```

When I open alertdialog I get an error (java.lang.NullPointerException) where the RadioGroup is added to the LinearLayout.
How can i do?
Thanks, Mattia

Answer (score 1):

```
RadioGroup azione = (RadioGroup) screenDialog.findViewById(R.id.azione_stop);
```

and `screenDialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOURXML);`

```
AlertDialog screenDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
screenDialog.setTitle("Captured Screen");
screenDialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOURXMLLAYOUT);

RadioGroup azione = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.azione_stop);

screenDialog.show();
```

Comment: screenDialog hasn't findViewById method.

Comment: are you set first `setContentView` ? then access first line...RadioGroup azione = (RadioGroup) screenDialog.findViewById(R.id.azione_stop);

Comment: If i add a textview instead of a radiogroup it works fine with the code i post

Comment: AlertDialog  screenDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

Comment: Now i get the error requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10123/discussion-between-samir-mangroliya-and-pindol)